# I get wrong results (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I run my code it works but if i go under -273.15 degree it has a bug.

When  i enter 10 or a number above -273.15 it works fine.

But if I enter a sting or char it works and wants me to retry it

But if i go under -273.15 and then retry it with 10 or a number higher then -273.15 it give a wrong result.

TY for the help.

```py
def get_temperature():
    while True:
        celsius = input("Degree in Celsius ")
        try:
            celsius = float(celsius)
            return celsius
        except ValueError:
            print("Try numbers.")


def is_it_to_cold(celsius):
    while True:
        if celsius >= -273.15:
            return celsius
        else:
            print("not below -273.15 ")
            celsius = get_temperature()


def convert_to_kalvin(celsius):
    kalvin = celsius + 273.15
    return kalvin


if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    is_it_to_cold(celsius)
    print("str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " +" Degree Kalvin.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `celsius` object passed to the method `is_it_to_cold()` and the one defined with `celsius = get_temperature()` are different objects.

So, when the use inputs a temperature less than `-273.15`, you take the new user input but the one defined in the `main` still holds the old value. You can verify the same by adding print statement as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    is_it_to_cold(celsius)
    print(celsius) # it still holds the old user input
    print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " Degree Kalvin.")
```

The easy fix would be to just update the celsius object with the return value from `is_it_to_cold` as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    celsius = is_it_to_cold(celsius) 
    print(celsius) # it now holds the correct user input
    print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " Degree Kalvin.")
```

However, I would also recommend a bit of restructuring with the code by continuously asking the user for input based on the outcome of `is_it_to_cold` and return a boolean `True/False` based on the condition.

```
def get_temperature():
    while True:
        celsius = input("Degree in Celsius ")
        try:
            celsius = float(celsius)
            if is_it_to_cold(celsius):
                continue
            return celsius
        except ValueError:
            print("Try numbers.")


def is_it_to_cold(celsius):
    if celsius >= -273.15:
        return False
    else:
        print("not below -273.15 ")
        return True

def convert_to_kalvin(celsius):
    kalvin = celsius + 273.15
    return kalvin

if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " Degree Kalvin.")
```

Comment: there is also an obvious issue with quotes in the `print()` statement which is clearly highlighted in the question itself.

Comment: it was by miss typing. Its not in the original code. And ty for the restructure suggestion

Comment: Glad to be able to help! Also, I understood that it was a typo with posting the question as it was pretty obvious to include in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at the end is it to cold you don't reassign Celsius if it is so it keeps the old entered Celsius instead of reassign.

```
def get_temperature():
    while True:
        celsius = input("Degree in Celsius ")
        try:
            celsius = float(celsius)
            return celsius
        except ValueError:
            print("Try numbers.")


def is_it_to_cold(celsius):
    while True:
        if celsius >= -273.15:
            return celsius
        else:
            print("not below -273.15 ")
            celsius = get_temperature()
            print(celsius)
            return celsius


def convert_to_kalvin(celsius):
    kalvin = celsius + 273.15
    return kalvin


if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    print(celsius)
     #This below should fix your error
    celsius = is_it_to_cold(celsius)
    print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + "+Degree Kalvin.")
```

This was the error

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    celsius = get_temperature()
    print(celsius)
    #By not reassign it you keep the old temperture
    celsius = is_it_to_cold(celsius)
    print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + "+Degree Kalvin.")
```

So just add celsius =

before the is_it_cold(celsius) to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of false

```
print("str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " Degree Kalvin.")
```

And this is the true

```
print(str(convert_to_kalvin(celsius)) + " Degree Kalvin.")
```

Comment: Havent tryed yours